# Else statement returning to original script

Tags: python, sqlite, if-statement

I'm working on a login script using Python and SQLite and I just came across a weird error.

This is the code I got:

```
while c.fetchone() is not None:
    if oper in ["3350",""]:
        print(term.move(28,1))
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system("python /SABB/app1.py")

    elif oper == "1010":
        os.system("python /SABB/app2.py")

if oper == "/":
    sys.exit()

else:
    main('self')
```

It validates the username and password, and depending on the "oper" that was typed in, open either one of the available applications, which is working correctly.

But the else statement seems to have created a problem. When the user exits the applications, they are sent back to the login script. The same behavior as if the code was:

```
else:
    os.system("python /SABB/app1.py")
    main('self')
```

Any ideas?

[EDIT] Here's the full script: https://gist.github.com/lovemac15/d04e224a02d0497ae68b

Comment: Where is the definition of main function?

Comment: @YCFlame I just edited the question and added a link to the full script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having the same issue as me, I solved it by replacing 'os.system' with 'subprocess.call' to call the external scripts.

Hope that helps! :D